# I am made of love and I am made of war, guess what I am and became the next star

Tags: riddle, word

- I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me (Edit)
- I am most popular than any other
- People use me often when they want to be informal
- Dirty minds see something lascivious in me
- I am loved by road trippers
- Some isolated people in the world have never seen me
- I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you
- I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins
- I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me (edit)
- I am often the beginning of some ends, but I am not the apocalypse (edited)
- My grandgrandfather spirit is hidden in multiple things, like trees
- I've been 16 for long time now, but that depends on the mood, on self-confident days I pretend I am 80, on miserable ones 112, etc...

**What am I?**

Comment: Hint: The title is just poetic license, consider the clues better

Comment: And use imagination!

Comment: There is very little that there are trillions of and nothing that I know of that man has made that are that numerous. Is that a literal number or an exaggeration?

Comment: what is a road tripper?

Comment: @Aequitas someone who goes on, or is currently on a road trip?

Comment: @TracyCramer I think it's a literal number, but I don't think it's a physical object.

Comment: @Jon Hleb You just typed it

Comment: I feel like the more clues you give, the more confusing it gets

Comment: It's not X and it's not Y and it's not E...

Comment: I may have the answer but I cannot post an answer due to this question being highly active and me not having earned  at least 10 rep.. What can I do ?

Comment: Oops.. I dont know..

Comment: @Oddrigue Well, let's get you there then ;)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post this either, unfortunately, so anyone should feel free to steal this answer--are you the letter P?

Comment: I believe @KitKat has it right. "Look better within you" was super cheeky now that I've seen this. Would still love to see fully-written explanations.

Comment: @anodyne here's what i have: the 16/80/112 was what tipped me off--it's the 16th letter of the alphabet and 80/112 in ascii. informal = using p for "pretty", or ":p", which OP uses a lot in the comments (and they said to look in comments). beginning of some ends = the first letter of "period"? mutilate = flip to be b, d, or q. a bunch of the others are the same as MacGyver88's initial guess of 'E' (see previous edit to that answer, that OP says was close).

Comment: @KitKat There's no way that's not correct. Thanks for writing out the ones I was unsure on.

Comment: @anodyne heck yeah! feel free to use it as an answer. Here are some of my other thoughts, tho i'm less confident in them: weapon = a little sword? road trippers = pee breaks, or else just the word has two ps in it. grandgrandfathers spirit in multiple things = if that's 's', it's in plural words. not super sure of those, but... :D

Comment: amazing! got the clues in the comments even! Yes its P, but I need an answer to put the final solution!

Comment: Yay! Nice riddle. I unfortunately do not have enough rep to add an answer to this question, so I give my blessing to whoever wants to type it up. :)

Comment: I thought it was the letter 'p' (lowercase specifically) too, mainly because of 16 and @user65573 comments about letters, but I didn't know how to answer many of the questions. Looking forward to the solution. How many rep points do you need to answer @KitKat?

Comment: @pholly just 10, on this specific site--unfortunately I saw this on HNQ and came here from there. You should go for it!

Comment: @user65573 you should post the answer yourself, quoting Kitkat's comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On behalf of user @KitKat, who has not enough points to answer but has guessed it, I will write the answer, taking profit and writing complete answer:

You are

> The letter P

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me:

> Rotate P 90°, it's a gun/cannonball

I am most popular than any other:

> This was tricked in a literal sense. P is the letter with more presence in the word popular, as well as soundly characteristic of the abbreviation PoP

People use me often when they want to be informal:

> :p or ;p are widely used contemporary signals on messages that don't have to be taken too serious

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me:

> P (rotate again, it was a way to reinforce that the clues were pretty visual/figurative/symbolic)

I am loved by road trippers:

> [Link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Parking_icon.svg)

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me:

> It's hard to live this world without ever seeing a latin character, but it is possible if you don't have access to media, signs etc..

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins:

> Typographies

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me:

> There's no point on half P or a quarter of P, but if you split it you got shapes that resemble D or l

I am often the beginning of the end, but I am not the apocalypse:

> P.S (Post Scriptum) at the end of a letter

My grandgrandfather spirit is hidden in multiple things, like trees:

> π, the old spelling for /p/, is "hidden" on everything with a circumference, like a tree trunk

I've been 16 for long time now, but that depends on the mood, on self-confident days I pretend I am 80, on miserable ones 112, etc..:

> P is 16 ordinal letter of alphabet, but it can be represented in several ways, like 80 in ASCII for upper case, 112 for lower

Comment: Dang I had it too with half the clues, gj KitKat

Comment: What does it have to do with the title tho ?

Comment: I said in the very first comment "Hint: The title is just poetic license, consider the clues better ". But it got hidden after a lot of people commented on the question discussion

Answer (score 15):

I'll admit some of the clues have been stretched in my interpretation.
Are you:

> **Hydrogen?**

*I can be a weapon if you know how to handle me*

> Hydrogen bombs need to be handled carefully, due to their trigger being a fission bomb

*I am most popular than any other*

> Hydrogen is the most abundant element in the universe

*People use me often when they want to be informal*

> The first syllable of "hydrogen" is "hi", an informal or casual greeting instead of a more formal "hello" *(bit of a stretch)*

*Dirty minds see something lascivious in me*

> The simplest representation of a hydrogen atom is a dot/point inside a circle, which is also the schoolkid representation of a breast

*I am loved by road trippers*

> Hydrogen is a significant component of hydrocarbons, one of which is the fuel used by road trippers *(bit of a stretch again!)*

Title: *I am made of love and I am made of war, guess what I am*

> I'm drawing a blank here, but two lines of thought are:
>   1. Love and war are Venus and Mars, represented by the female sign ♀ and male sign ♂, those two sexes fuse to reproduce, the fusion of hydrogen powers a star
>   2. Love and war are opposites, just like the dot and circle are opposites (i.e. presence and absence)

*... and became the next star*

> Hydrogen fusion is what powers stars, the conversion of hydrogen to helium

Comment: Very good answer. The answer is less literal that that, but it fits well! Look better within you :p

Comment: It even fits the extra clue - "I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me". The hydrogen nucleus is just one proton, it can't be fissioned in the same way as other atomic nuclei. If it is "split", it is reduced to subatomic particles.

Comment: I was indeed thinking atoms, but these don't fit most other clues lol

Comment: I was thinking a "thumbs up"

Comment: Love and war are not opposites, as the love of a woman has caused a few wars/feuds, and love of power and resources have caused many other wars.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are a:

> book

I can be a weapon if you know how to handle me

> Knowledge is the best weapon

I am most popular than any other

> Books are the number one thing that people read

People use me often when they want to be informal

> Casual reading- isn't that what most people read for?

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> Different genres

I am loved by road trippers

> Books can lead you to what you want, like a road tripper

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Yes, developing countries, not all can read books!

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> Books, magazines, newspapers... they're all man made and they all can enlighten you!

Title:
I am made of love and I am made of war

> Books are made out of love by people who want to learn. Our past wars are all recorded in the form of paper

What I am became the next star

> The first books were definitely a hit and now look at all the different types of books, stories became part of people's lives... what a star!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! An excellent answer you got here!

Comment: As a context concept, you are the closer answer, but the approach is less literal and more figurative, and this is a huge hint!

Answer (score 9):

Is it a

> **hand**?

*I can be a weapon if you know how to handle me*

> Most self-defence teach to make your body a weapon, especially your hands

*I am most popular than any other*

> This may refer to the hands being most used on a daily basis

*People use me often when they want to be informal*

> A couple of hand gestures could be informal such as fist bumps, pat on back or shoulder.

*Dirty minds see something lascivious in me*

> Well...some gestures could convey obscene meanings

*I am loved by road trippers*

> This may refer to a hitchhiking gesture.

Comment: Very creative answer, it totally fits the clues so it deserves an extra clue

Comment: I thought this was the answer too! Well, now I'm baffled.

Answer (score 6):

You could be a

> **FORK**

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me

> you could use a fork as a weapon

I am most popular than any other

> Fork is used more than a knife or spoon

People use me often when they want to be informal

> Using a fork to cut something rather than getting a knife

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> F@#$

I am loved by road trippers

> Fork in the road

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> They probably don't use silverware

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> Using shiny silverware may create light glaring

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> Most forks aren't exactly the same style

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me

> By bending a fork you can make something else. Don't know what, but hey.

Previous Answer

> **E** then **X** - OP said really close on E. Choose fork because ==E in my first answer looks like a fork.

Comment: For road trippers: rot13(R sbe rzcgl gnax, zrnaf n cvg fgbc gb fgergpu yrtf naq trg zber fanpxf.)

Comment: It's not, but you almost got it. Indeed you are amazingly close

Comment: This looks good! The second line could also be the one who gets the rot13(ibgr). Maybe twins refere to rot13(puebzbfbzrf).

Comment: There's 3-4 answers from you that can be considered correct :p

Comment: But the answer is not, just to clarify

Comment: @Tom is that a code?

Comment: @Aequitas, yes, rot13 replaces a letter with the 13th letter after/before it. Can use https://rot13.com/

Answer (score 6):

I think you are a:

> word

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me

> **S**word adding the "S" makes it a weapon

I am most popular than any other

> Words are the most popular form of comunication

People use me often when they want to be informal

> Words used as slang

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> *sexting??*

I am loved by road trippers

> Road trippers use lots of words in conversations

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Blind people can´t read so they can´t actually see words

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> Words are a man-made invention and along with other words make sentences or texts

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> There are many words in many different languages

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me

> A word divided doesn't make sense but there are some parts of words that make sense by themselves (prefixes, sufixes)

Answer (score 4):

Going off the comment hint on UnidentifiedX's great answer, you are a:

> story

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me (Edit)

> You can use a story as a weapon against an argument and, even if you don't, your story can seem (look) like a weapon to others.

I am most popular than any other

> Stories are popular ways to express an idea, transmit information, or amuse others. Technical manuals convey information and express ideas, but aren't popular unless they tell a story. Poems and songs that tell stories are often more popular than those that don't.

People use me often when they want to be informal

> When people want to get to know other people, they tend to tell stories, which is much less formal than reciting a resume or CV. You might tell a story about a scar or a fun project you are working on, rather than recite strict facts about what happened.

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> Stories can be told about a lot of things, and some people love to add double entendre's to make things more interesting. Some people hear them even when they aren't intended.

I am loved by road trippers

> To pass the time during a road trip, people tell each other stories. Either it's in the car, bus, truck, or whatever vehicle, or it's around the table at a restaurant, around a bonfire, or just chilling before bed.

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Stories are everywhere, but are only seen when written down. There are still a few isolated indigenous people that have never seen a book.

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> People make stories (ie. man-made), rather than animals, plants, or rocks having stories. People can tell stories about those things, but it's still the imagination of the human, not thing they are telling the story about. People often tell stories to give each other information or to help explain how a decision was or should be made.

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> There are more stories than can really be counted, and even with billions of people in the world, each one has their own large set of stories.

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me (edit)

> Most stories don't make sense if they are broken into parts. If you twist (mutilate) the meaning of a story, it can mean something completely different than the original intent.

I am made of love and I am made of war, guess what I am and became the next star

> Stories are usually made by people who love to tell stories, and almost everyone loves to hear one. Many stories are about war, and war makes a lot of stories to be told as warnings to others. The right story can be made into a play, TV series, or even a movie, and the author can become a star if any of those options become popular.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> BBC.

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me

> 1. The [bromobenzyl cyanide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromobenzyl_cyanide) (also known as BBC) is an obsolete lachrymatory agent introduced in World War I by the Allied Powers.

I am most popular than any other

> 2. The [British Broadcasting Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC) (also known as BBC) is the world's oldest national broadcaster and the largest broadcaster in the world by number of employees.

People use me often when they want to be informal

> 3. The barbecue (also known as BBC) are traditionally held outside. They could be small informal gatherings with a few people in a backyard or a formal event that could last all day, typically held for larger numbers of people.

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> 4. The big black cock (also known as BBC) is an internet slang used by dirty minds.

I am loved by road trippers

> 5. The [Big Block Chevrolet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevrolet_big-block_engine) engine (also known as BBC) is a term for a series of large displacement V8 engines for automobiles, used by road trippers.

The other five hints recall the previous five.

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> 3. Buddhist monks, who live in isolation, follow the tradition of never eating meat, so they never saw a barbecue in front of them.

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> 2. A newspaper is man-made, and with its friends (other newspapers, such as the New York Times and The Guardian) they can give a person knowledge and enlight them.

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> 1. There are trillions of atoms, but as this substance is composed of carbon, hydrogen and nitrogen, molecules that are more present in the universe, so most of them are like brothers.

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me (edit)

> 4. A penis is indivisible, but even if you mutilate it, it becomes something else (which, in this case, is a ground beef).

I am often the beginning of the end, but I am not the apocalypse

> 5. As American automobiles grew in size and weight following the Second World War, the engines powering them had to keep pace. Chevrolet had introduced its popular small block V8 in 1955, but needed something larger to power its medium duty trucks and the heavier cars that were on the drawing board. For this reason, this new series of engines (Big Block) was created. So this series marked the beginning of the end for the old engine series.

Comment: Amazing xd. Prize for the most witty answer of them all! actually if you read comments from other answers, the correct answer must be around the corner

Comment: isn't a barbeque usually abbreviated to BBQ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are a

> **Fire**

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me

> Fire a gun

I am most popular than any other

> Fire is hot

People use me often when they want to be informal

> Camp fire

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> Fire in his/her eye

I am loved by road trippers

> Need fire to cook

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> Fire/candle

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> ??

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me

> Smoke

I am often the beginning of the end, but I am not the apocalypse

> Fire burns down everything

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking:

> a guitar.

I'm not sure this is right, but a few of the clues are a good enough fit for me to take a punt.

I can be a weapon if you know how to handle me

> On a fairly loose level - music as propaganda, propaganda as a weapon.

I am most popular than any other

> The guitar is the foundation of Western pop music!

People use me often when they want to be informal

> This put me in mind of the proverbial someone at a party playing Wonderwall, and it also fits with the guitar being more commonly used in popular music than classical.

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> A comparison is sometimes made between the curves of a guitar and the bust-waist-hip curve.

I am loved by road trippers

> I'll be honest, I don't have a good one here; I think taking a guitar on a road trip makes thematic sense but I'm not aware of a specific thing here.

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Just straightforwardly factual here.

Title: I am made of love and I am made of war, guess what I am

> "Make love, not war"; but also "this machine kills fascists". Both well-known phrases with enough of a link for me to bring it in.

and became the next star

> As in pop star.

Comment: Last clue was to discard previous answer, but yours could fit as well so I am gonna give a new hint

Comment: ... can be a weapon ... guitars are sometimes referred to as axes

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> Paper / Cardboard

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me

> Board - Maybe?

I am most popular than any other

> Newspaper?

People use me often when they want to be informal

> ??

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> ??

I am loved by road trippers

> Reading books and / or holding signs?

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Paper is not used everywhere

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> Books

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> Other pieces of paper

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me (edit)

> Paper cant be divided by cut into smaller chunks?

Answer (score 2):

**What am I?**

> A banana.

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me (Edit)

> Bananas look like guns and are often used to comically portray guns.

I am most popular than any other

> With over one hundred million tons eaten a year, the banana is the most popular fruit.

People use me often when they want to be informal

> Not sure. Perhaps the Banana Equivalent Dose, a method of measuring radiation exposure where 1 BED is the radiation you get from eating a banana. Often used informally by people explaining radiation.

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> Well, it looks like... the male reproductive organ.

I am loved by road trippers

> Bananas are healthy yet small and tasty making them popular with road trippers.

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Bananas aren't available everywhere.

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> Bananas used to look like this:
>  [image: banana picture] (Bananas are actually berries.)
>  But we selectively bred them to be easy to hold, big, tasty, and to have (practically) no seeds. The modern banana is man-made.

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> Because of that selective breeding, almost all bananas around the world are closely related.

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me (edit)

> Not sure. Bananas are 'mutilated' when eaten, becoming white, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

After reading the answers and comments, I thought that you are

> Y

Because

> You look like a slingshot as a weapon, look like a funnel people wear on their heads to be informal, look like a car brand's symbol, you make texts with your friends and enlighten us, you have trillions of fraternal twins as Y cromosoms..

Comment: This also looks good! Fifth line can be the rot13(LZPN).

Comment: Almost got it, but not yet :p. There is a couple of clues on the comments I left to others

Answer (score 2):

A bit stretched, but can you be

> a (chess) pawn?

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me (Edit)

> Of course, even a pawn can be a weapon in the chess game when it's in the hands of an experienced player.

I am most popular than any other

> Of course, there are more pawns on the board than any other type of chess pieces.

People use me often when they want to be informal

> (Very stretched) When people agree to play (amateur, outside of tournaments etc.) chess with each other, they usually treat each other informally.

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> *Pawn* can be a homophone of *porn*, an abbreviation of pornography (which is lascivious).

I am loved by road trippers

> (Stretched) Maybe a reference that a pawn "travels" along its way on the board.

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> As well as all other chess pieces.

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> Of course, all pawns are man-made. When a pawn is with the other chess pieces in a set, you can play chess and thus become more enlightened.

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> Of course, most chess pawns are similar, but not all of them follow the same design.

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me (edit)

> Pawns can promote to other pieces when they reach the end of their way (not sure about being "mutilated")

I am often the beginning of the end, but I am not the apocalypse

> When most remaining pieces on the board are pawns, that's usually a sign of endgame (which is "the beginning of the end").

Answer (score 2):

You could be

> Social Media (or TWITTER using @)

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me (Edit)

> @weapon - <== not my actual handle

I am most popular than any other

> Twitter is probably the most popular social media site, uses "@"

People use me often when they want to be informal

> Using social media, Tweeting with "@", or E-Mail to @someWebSite

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> I'm sure you can find bad things on Twitter/social media

I am loved by road trippers

> Sharing photos on social media

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> never seen the internet or social media

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> social media can give you lots of information

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> Websites and posts are all web pages with different things on them

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me (edit)

> A web page will change if you change the code, bending a "@" you can make a really long d, q, b, g, 9, or 6, etc...

I am often the beginning of the end, but I am not the apocalypse

> Email address like someone@somesite.com - "@" marks where the end begins, but is not the end.

My grandfather spirit is hidden in multiple things, like trees

> Twitter's logo is a bird. Birds hide in trees. Before the internet were books made from trees.

Title

> Internet star, Social Media Star/Icon, Twitter star

Previous

> E, X, FORK, F or f, Website using @

Thoughts

> Haven't received feedback yet. So, I'm thinking plausible but not close enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> A gas

I can be a weapon if you know how to handle me

> Poison gas

I am most popular than any other

> Hydrogen is the most abundant element in the universe

People use me often when they want to be informal

> Farts !

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> Autoerotic asphyxia ? (see David Carradine) Fart fetishists ?

I am loved by road trippers

> You need gas to run a car

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Primitive tribes may have never *seen* gas

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> Humans produce methane and we use(d) it for lighting

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> Dyhydrogen ?

I am indivisible

> In the litteral sense, it is hard to cut a gas in two ?

Comment: It's a well reasearched answer, but the solution is not scientifical, try to think with a child's mind :p

Answer (score 1):

Propane gas has most of the required elements described in the question.

Propane can be used as a weapon.

Propane is very popular in most cities on this planet.

People use it when they are not formally dressed.

Dirty minds see some lasciviousness in propane.

Many vehicles use propane as fuel.

Many isolated places do not use it.

There are trillions upon trillions of molecules of propane gas.

If we burn propane it gets mutilated.

Comment: You are going to have to be far more descriptive with your explanation than that for this site.

Comment: It's my first riddle, I started with deliberatedly tricky questions, and got more concrete after feedback. I never played against whole internet, Ill be a bit more evident next time. I played as a contestant in other riddles here and I see its much more difficult when you are in the other side!!

Comment: @user65573.You do very well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, second attempt :

You are

> Chopsticks

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me (Edit)

> You can hit people with sticks and chopsticks are basically tiny sticks. Sticks.

I am most popular than any other

> Most commonely used utensil in the world (I believe)

People use me often when they want to be informal

> When ordering chinese food (?)

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> With a little bit of imagination, you could do all sorts of things with chopsticks...

I am loved by road trippers

> Easy to eat on the road with one hand (?)

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Some people have never eating with chopsticks

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> Man made (obvious), enlighten either you could burn them as they are usually wooden or maybe when eating with your friends is enlightening (?)

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> trillions of chopsticks in the world and they come in pair

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me (edit)

> you have to break them down the middle to be able to use them

I am often the beginning of the end, but I am not the apocalypse

> "Sticks and stones"

My grandgrandfather spirit is hidden in multiple things, like trees

> ...they're made out of wood ?

Answer (score 0):

You are

> The letter E

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me

> A [sai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sai_(weapon)) looks like an E if gripped in a hand

I am most popular than any other

> E is the most common letter (at least in English and I guess in related indo germanic languages)

People use me often when they want to be informal

> Ehhhh...

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> Honestly not sure about that one

I am loved by road trippers

> Could be a fork in a road or stand for an electronic map

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Some people don't have a written language at all.

I am man-made and when I am with my friends I can enlighten you

> The alphabet is obviously man-made. Many letters combined can impart knowledge.

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> This could be numerous fonts that all contain the same letters, but each in a slightly different design.

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me (edit)

> Not sure about this one...

I am often the beginning of the end, but I am not the apocalypse

> The first letter of "end" is e, but the first letter of "apocalypse" isn't.

My grandgrandfather spirit is hidden in multiple things, like trees

> Maybe this refers to spoken language as the "grandfather" of written text?

Answer (score 0):

You are

> freedom

I look like a weapon if you know how to handle me

> Like hippy revolution.

I am most popular than any other

> Freedom is very popular topic: freedom of speech, politics etc. You meet it in everyday life.

People use me often when they want to be informal

> In informal situation people are more free in speech and behaviour.

Dirty minds see something lascivious in me

> Free love

I am loved by road trippers

> They are free, they can go wherever they want.

Some isolated people in the world have never seen me

> Isolation means lack of freedom.

I have trillions of twins, but they are mostly fraternal twins

> Freedom have many forms that depends on culture, society etc.

I am indivisible but I can become something else if you mutilate me

> When freedom is limited it turns to slavery.